# Insert hyperlink from form to pdf

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to link a questionnaire composed in Forms to a pdf document. Ideally I'd like to web host the document and link directly to a page or section of said document.

Is there a way to, using script,

1. include a named hyperlink in a Form? And,
2. make the link point to a web hosted pdf at a particular page or section?

Thanks in advance,
Zak

Comment: Instead of aking for a solution, you should describe your problem as precisely as possible and show what you have done so far to solve it : [How do I ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You could add it as an image.  You could take the image off your screen with a program like Paint Shop Pro or Snagit and then upload it to the form as a jpg.

Answer (score 0):

This is image was taken from a PDF and saved as a jpg. And then uploaded to a form.

[image]

Here's an example of adding an image to a form:

```
// Open a form by ID and add a new image item
 var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
 var img = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png');
 form.addImageItem()
     .setTitle('Google')
     .setHelpText('Google Logo') // The help text is the image description
     .setImage(img);
```

Here's the [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/image-item) to reference documentation.